# springboot RestTemplate call url and https response headers(content-type:audio/wav) ,how to save as *.wav file?

Tags: java, wav, spring-resttemplate

I use spring RestTemplate to call the the Third-party services，

```
ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

result like this:

forEntity
status:200
headers:
content-type=audio/wav
body:"RIFFä,,,xxxxxxx......"

response is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3yLG.png)
the body seems to wav data, I want to save the data to wav file.

if I Go directly to the link in chrome, it's ok to play, and download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RestTemplate.execute` instead, which allows you to attach a `ResponseExtractor`, in which you have access to the `response body` which an `InputStream`, we take that `InputStream` and write it to a file

```
   restTemplate.execute(
            url, 
            HttpMethod.GET,
            request -> {}, 
            response -> {
                //get response body as inputstream
                InputStream in = response.getBody();
                //write inputstream to a local file
                Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C:/path/to/file.wav"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                return null;
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java a `String` is not the same as a `byte[]` array.
Therefore treating audio-content (which is binary data)
as a string (i.e. text data) is begging for problems.
Instead, you should get the response body as `byte[]`.
Then you can save the bytes to a file.
For example like this:

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> entity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, byte[].class);
byte[] body = entity.getBody();
Path path = Paths.get("example.wav");
Files.write(path, body);
```